# Parse Error while installing the higher version apk

Tags: android, installation, version, apk

In my application I have a functionality to download the higher version apk have to install the new apk automatically. I am downloading the application from the server and storing it in a folder.Then trying to install it . But getting Parse Error. Some days before it was was working fine , but now getting error. If go to the folder in which new apk is downloaded and try to install it overriding the previous apk, it is installing correctly. But I need the functionality of auto install. Please help me.
Thanks
Santanu

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this error in the scenario only once before, when I was doing the same thing and downloading the apk to the internal storage and trying to install it from there. This doesn't work, as the PackageManager cannot access the update apk there.

Try downloading to the External Storage and installing from there instead.

Comment: I am storing the downloaded apk file in the external storage. And then installing the apk from there, but getting error. Please help.

Comment: Post some code then. And make sure the file you've downloaded isn't corrupted. Try putting the apk manually on the external storage and installing that one

Comment: I have a silly mistake to access the apk file, sorry for that. Now installation occurring, but a strange problem is occurring. After install, two option coming Open and Done. If I choose Open, it is not opening the application, it is working like Done option.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably don't have a main activity defined in your app. Either way, that is now unrelated to the question, and you should open another question with the relevant code and details for that

Comment: @santanu what was the mistake you were doing to get that parsing error? and what you did to correct it?

Comment: @RaghavSood I have a low cost device with no NAND and no SD card. Is there any internal storage that package manager and user app both could access? for example: /data or just /(like linux).